# Can you, Will you, Could you and Would you?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, questions, can-modal

One of my textbooks says that "would you ~?" is the politest of the four to ask someone a favor.

Another textbook, however, says that "will you" is the least polite and that "can you" and "could you" are politer than "will you" and "would you".

Another one says that "will you" is politer than "can you" and that you use it to someone you don't know well (like a taxi driver).

I'm confused.  When should I use which one to whom?  Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: These might help, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/when-should-we-use-can-could-will-would and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23223/would-you-and-could-you-and-so-on

Comment: "Will" is closer to giving an order than the others. If I request something beginning with "Will you..." even if I add "please",  I expect to be obeyed, so which one you use depends on context and interpersonal relationships.